# Android cannot insert into SQLite3 DB

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am trying to insert some data into and SQLite DB on android, but the code below just does not work. Can anyone spot the issue.

```
db = this.openOrCreateDatabase("data_7.db", 0, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'group' (my_id TEXT NOT NULL, my_key TEXT NOT NULL)");
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO 'group' (my_id, my_key) VALUES ('abc', '123')");
db.close();
```

After running the code I extracted the SQLite file off the emulator and opened it using an SQLite GUI viewer, the table was created but no data was inserted.

**Note:**

- I have searched through this site all day and could not find a
  suitable answer to this issue
- I would like to do this without the aid of helper methods like
  .insert(). ie. I need to user pure SQL

Comment: Try getting rid of the single quotes around the table name? That's the only thing that I see that might be off there...

Comment: in which method did you write this code ?

Comment: @Grishu no Error, the data is just not inserted.

Comment: @jsoft tried to remove the quotes, no luck, the data still does not insert

Comment: @KhalidTaha I wrote this in the onClick() method in my activity

Answer (score 0):

Try out this way:

> ```
> "INSERT INTO group (my_id, my_key) " + "VALUES ('" + field_one + "', '" + field_two + "')";
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the table in the method `onCreate()` that is found on the Dababase class that you have to build like this:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final String DB_NAME="YourDBName";
    public static final int VERSION=1;
    Context context=null;
    public Database(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        this.context=context;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        try
        {
            String sql="CREATE TABLE group(my_id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, my_key TEXT NOT NULL)";
            String insert="INSERT INTO group VALUES('abc','123');";
            db.execSQL(sql);     
            db.execSQL(insert);  
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS group");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

Make sure that the old database is deleted or change the version to 2 in order to execute the query.
If you need to execute this query you need to write:

```
Database db=new Database();
SQLiteDatabasse read=db.getReadableDatabase();
```